# Как в консоли Open Server поменять права на папку?

Tags: консоль, openserver, chmod

Как в консоли Open Server поменять права на папку?

При вводе команды chmod -r 777 art-code
Выдает:
"chmod" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: потому что в windows нет chmod. ... там есть `icalcs`..... примерно так `icacls "C:\MyFolder" /grant Users:F` или `icacls "C:\MyFolder" /q /c /t /grant Users:F`  ......... `F - дает полный доступ, 
/q /c /t - для вложенных папок тоже`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Comment: ...[Windows и в нем нет понятия права доступа как в Linux](http://boardrussia.ru/Zadat_-prava-na-papku-v-Open-Server-art1766.html)